# Remove duplicates from a SQL query

Tags: mysql, duplicates

This seems to have been asked a few times but I can't get my query to work.

I have tow tables one of users and one of registration details.

```
user.id  user.name   Registration.status Registration.statusname
  1        Homer            70              Booked
  2        Maggie           70              Booked
  2        Maggie           10              Cancelled
  3        Bart             70              Booked
  4        Lisa             70              Booked
  4        Lisa             10              Cancelled
```

What I would like is a query to find duplicate `user.id` remove the 70 and keep the 10 in registration.id.

I don't want the 70 deleted just not on the query.

Here's the part of the code that matters.

```
$course = $_POST["course"];
$date= $_POST["date"];
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT firstname, lastname, data, name, statuscode,   statusname, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestart),'%d/%m/%y') AS timestart,
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timefinish),'%d/%m/%y') AS timefinish

FROM mdl_facetoface 
INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface_sessions ON   mdl_facetoface_sessions.facetoface=mdl_facetoface.id
 INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface_sessions_dates  ON mdl_facetoface_sessions.id=mdl_facetoface_sessions_dates.sessionid
 INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface_signups  ON mdl_facetoface_sessions.id=mdl_facetoface_signups.sessionid
 INNER JOIN mdl_user ON mdl_facetoface_signups.userid=mdl_user.id
 INNER JOIN mdl_user_info_data  ON mdl_user_info_data.userid = mdl_user.id
 INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface_signups_status   ON  mdl_facetoface_signups.id=mdl_facetoface_signups_status.signupid
 INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface_status  ON mdl_facetoface_signups_status.statuscode=mdl_facetoface_status.id

WHERE name LIKE '%".$course."%'
AND mdl_user_info_data.fieldid ='3'
AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestart),'%d/%m/%y') LIKE '%".$date."%'
AND firstname <> 'test'
AND lastname <> 'test'
AND (statuscode='10' OR statuscode ='70')


ORDER BY statuscode DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should group it by a column (foreign key) that connects the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first sample I would offer something like this:

```
select
    user.id, min(user.name), min(registration.status), max(registration.statusname)
...
group by user.id
```

This works because you know that you want to only keep the lowest status (10 < 70) and the highest status name (Cancelled > Booked). Adding more codes would likely complicate the logic.

As for the actual query you posted the pictures gets more hazy since I don't know what's going on with all those tables.

Comment: I've formatted the demo output to make it easier to understand. The duplicate user row with a 70 will be eliminated if a 10 and a 70 exist.

Comment: Formatted output helps nobody when we don't know the input. But I already made sense of what you want and gave a answer that addresses that issue.

Comment: Didn't work. However I've found another column in another table that changes 0 to 1 when the info changes.

Comment: Another column wouldn't impact the aggregates I wrote. You'll have to show me what you're actually trying or I can't help.

Comment: I should have been clearer in my last comment, Problems sorted. On the column that changes a 0 to 1. there is a table with the codes 10 - 100.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I should have been clearer in my last comment, Problem sorted. regarding the new table I found. there are three columns one with the codes 10 - 100 and one with 0 and a date stamp. When a person books on a course they get a 70 in the first table in the other table the 70 changes from a 0 to a 1 if they cancel the 70 changes from a 1 to a 0 and the 10 changes to a 1. all I need to do is see where the 1 is and the date it changed. I can now charge people a cancellation fee for booking on loads of free courses with no intention of turning up and cancelling on the morning.